# how to onclick for pairs of images randomly in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
/* egg & broke egg  pair1  lite & broke lite pair2 pot & frys pair3 */
```

I would like to know how to make the images pair up or team up. So when you click the egg image it disappears and the broken egg appears. Then this image should also disappear then and one of the other two teams appear randomly lite click lite broke lite appears and disappears randomly and click pot it turns into frys then frys disappears and turns into a random team.

```
  </head>

  <body onLoad="setRandomImage()"> 

  <img id="egg.png" src= "http//"onClick="setRandomImage();"/>
  <img id="brokeEgg.png" src= "https://" style="display:none"/>

<img id="lite.png" src= "http://" style="display:none"/>
<img id="brokeLite.png" src= "http://" style="display:none"/>

<img id="pot.jpg" src= "https://style="display:none"/>
<img id="frys.jpg" src= "http://style="display:none"/>


<script type="text/javascript">  



    var myShapes=     ["egg.png","brokeEgg.png","lite.png","brokeLite.png","pot.jpg","frys.jpg"    ];



    function setRandomImage() {

    var imgElem = document.getElementById("egg.png")

    imgElem.setAttribute('src',myShapes[Math.floor(Math.random()*6)]);


    };

    </script>
```

Comment: thank you for your time i just wanted to say im a preschool student at best with this so forgive mw if i seem slow but im not for sure how to do that but i will give it a shot!

Comment: preschool? and you're coding? wow. my niece is at preschool and she's not even learnt to tie her shoes...

Comment: lol ...well... ya know, i catch on fast:) Yeah i wish!!! that  would be large, i meant what i know now about js my skills is equal to a pre schooler compared to most people on here seems like they got  A masters or at least college grad!

Comment: haha, I would think most people here are still learning. remember, making mistakes is a good thing. Just be open, show your work, and try not to get offended when people make harsh comments (and they will)

Comment: Yeah Harsh is nicely put im still learning how to use this site i kept getting edited by other users questions on hold its hard out here.. lol but thank you for the info and help its greatly appreciated we need more people like you...BLESSINGS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simplified one by making use of HTML [**`data-*`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attributes, but take in consideration:

- The value `data-image-seq` attribute *must* be `img` followed by a number.
- These numbers *must* be sequenced

**Updated**

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/apkac1re/5/)

```js
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.imgs-wrapper img'),
  currentIMG = 1;

// attach click events on odd images only, egg, lite, pot, hi1, hello1
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i += 2) {
  addEvent(imgs[i], 'click');
}

function addEvent(element, event) {
  element.addEventListener(event, function() {
    var imgSeq = element.getAttribute('data-image-seq'),
      nextImgSeq, nextImg, shownIMG;

    imgSeq = parseInt(imgSeq.replace('img', ''), 10);
    nextImgSeq = (imgSeq < imgs.length) ? (imgSeq + 1) : 1;
    nextImg = 'img[data-image-seq=img' + nextImgSeq + ']';
    element.style.display = 'none';
    shownIMG = document.querySelector(nextImg);
    shownIMG.style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(function() {
      shownIMG.style.display = 'none';
      showRandomImg();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function showRandomImg() {
  var randomIMG = returnRandomOddNum();
  randomIMG = (randomIMG !== currentIMG) ? randomIMG : returnRandomOddNum();
  currentIMG = randomIMG;
  randomIMG = 'img[data-image-seq=img' + randomIMG + ']';
  document.querySelector(randomIMG).style.display = 'block';
}

function returnRandomOddNum() {
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length);
  randomNum = (randomNum % 2 != 0) ?  randomNum : randomNum + 1;
  return randomNum;
}
```

```css
.imgs-wrapper { position: relative; }
.imgs-wrapper { cursor: pointer; }
.hide-me { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="imgs-wrapper">
  <img data-image-seq="img1" src="//dummyimage.com/150x50?text=egg">
  <img data-image-seq="img2" src="//dummyimage.com/150x50?text=broke egg" class="hide-me">
  <img data-image-seq="img3" src="//dummyimage.com/150x50?text=lite" class="hide-me">
  <img data-image-seq="img4" src="//dummyimage.com/150x50?text=broke light" class="hide-me">
  <img data-image-seq="img5" src="//dummyimage.com/150x50?text=pot" class="hide-me">
  <img data-image-seq="img6" src="//dummyimage.com/150x50?text=frys" class="hide-me">
  <img data-image-seq="img7" src="//dummyimage.com/150x50?text=Hi1" class="hide-me">
  <img data-image-seq="img8" src="//dummyimage.com/150x50?text=Hi2" class="hide-me">
  <img data-image-seq="img9" src="//dummyimage.com/150x50?text=Hello1" class="hide-me">
  <img data-image-seq="img10" src="//dummyimage.com/150x50?text=Hello2" class="hide-me">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for that! But i can not have a click function for the broke egg the broke lite or frys.  team1 (egg/broke egg) team2 (lite/ broke lite) team3 (pot/frys) they need to appear randomly by teams.click the egg image it disappears and the broke egg appears and disappears then either of the other two teams appear randomly click lite broke lite appears and disappears randomly and click pot it turns into frys then frys disappears and turns into a random team

Comment: ok, how'd the broke egg, broke lite or frys disappear after we show them?

Comment: im sorry im not sure what u mean but im guessing setTimeout function im guessing don't qoute me though

Comment: so say if you had team1 (hi &hi1) team2 (hi2 &hi3) team3 (hi4 & hi5) when you click hi it turns into hi1, hi1 disappears without a click and turns into one of the other teams randomly random team every time. click hi2 it turns into hi3 and hi4 when clicked turns into hi5 that should be everytime, the only thing that should change random is the teams

Comment: @ Mi-Creativity WELL OMG, i think thats it, i got what i asked for, its working like A charm!!!!! im sorry about the delayed response i fell asleep and now i got to head out to work, im thinking of calling in sick today and finish up, i cant thank you enough for helping me out with this, i think i got my first grey hair trying to figure this out thanks a MILLION!

Comment: Also if you don't mind me asking how long did it take for you to get great at javascript?

Comment: I'm not great at javascript there're thousands much better than me, but practicing and facing challenges those we or other people meet, like here on S.O, also having good programming background of making big use of little stuff works the same in most programming languages not only javascript.

Comment: You welcome and I'm glad it helped, you may consider checking this answer as correct answer if it helped you and/or voting it up, it's up to you mate :)

Comment: just getting home sure thing i will do that i wasn't aware of voting it up or checking this answer as correct answer just learned something else!

Comment: Thank you, have a good time, learn and practice and enjoy coding!

Comment: Thank You again@ Mi-Creativity you did give me what i ask for and i'm thankful for that! But i am so stuck still trying to do this on my own, i don't know if i mention i'm a rookie/novice at best, also is your method only javascript or some J query to??? showRandomImg& returnRandomOddNum functions i don't understand Can you show this method in layman's terms, or javascript for DUMMIES??? if not i totally understand its kinda like when someone ask to bum a cigarette from you, and then have the balls to ask for a lite too. smh

Comment: You welcome and Yes it is pure javascript, you don't see me including jQuery in the HTML even. but I don't know why it is not working on your own case

Comment: the `returnRandomOddNum()` function generates a random number, between **`1`** and **`9`**, then using [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) it checks if the randomly generated number in the previous step is odd or not by calculating the *reminder* of division by two `(randomNum % 2 != 0)`, the reminder is *not* zero, then the number is odd, we return it, if the reminder is zero then we have an even number, we increase it by **`1`** to make it odd and we return it

Comment: the `showRandomImg()` first get the randomly generated odd number from `returnRandomOddNum()`, then again using the ternary operator condition to check if the random odd number we got from `returnRandomOddNum()` function is same as the currently being shown image `currentIMG`, if it is the same then we call the `returnRandomOddNum()` function to get another random odd number different than the `currentIMG`, then we use it as selector with `document.querySelector()` to get the image we are going to show, give its `display:block` to show it and then we update the value of `currentIMG` for future

Comment: I have updated the answer with changed code in the two functions to make it a bit clearer, keep in mind that the more images you have the bigger range of randomly generated numbers you get.. also, are you getting any errors in the console **`F12`** ?

Comment: i Apologize about the late reply just getting home i did not check that but by you updating the answer with the changed code it did make it clearer! Much LOVE for helping out again that should sum it up, i really appreciate that Thank You Again!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to toggle the visibility of two elements on click:

```js
      function bindToggleVisibilityOnClick(firstElemId, secondElemId) {
          var firstElement = document.getElementById(firstElemId);
          var secondElement = document.getElementById(secondElemId);
          
          firstElement.onclick = function() { toggleVisibility(firstElement, secondElement); };
          secondElement.onclick = function() {  toggleVisibility(secondElement, firstElement); };
        }

    function toggleVisibility(checkElem, otherElem){
            // If target is invisible
            if (checkElem.style.display == "none" 
                //|| checkElem.style.visibility == "hidden"
            ) {
              checkElem.style.display = "block";
              // checkElem.style.visibility = "visible";
              otherElem.style.display = "none"
              // otherElem.style.visibility = "hidden";          
            }
            else {
              otherElem.style.display = "block";
              checkElem.style.display = "none"
              // checkElem.style.visibility = "hidden";                
            }
          };

    bindToggleVisibilityOnClick("egg", "brokenEgg");
```

```css
#egg       { display: block; }
#brokenEgg { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="egg"><p>hi</p></div>
<div id="brokenEgg"><p>hi2</p></div>
```

Use as such:

```
// Should now toggle visibility on click
bindToggleVisibilityOnClick("egg", "brokenEgg");
```

Also note I've left lines to toggle `visibility` instead of `display`, which will hide the element but leave the space that it takes up.

**EDIT**: If you want it to change once and not revert, comment out that second binding in the function as follows:

```js
      function bindToggleVisibilityOnClick(firstElemId, secondElemId) {
          var firstElement = document.getElementById(firstElemId);
          var secondElement = document.getElementById(secondElemId);
          
          firstElement.onclick = function() { toggleVisibility(firstElement, secondElement); };
          //secondElement.onclick = function() {  toggleVisibility(secondElement, firstElement); };
        }

    function toggleVisibility(checkElem, otherElem){
            // If target is invisible
            if (checkElem.style.display == "none" 
                //|| checkElem.style.visibility == "hidden"
            ) {
              checkElem.style.display = "block";
              // checkElem.style.visibility = "visible";
              otherElem.style.display = "none"
              // otherElem.style.visibility = "hidden";          
            }
            else {
              otherElem.style.display = "block";
              checkElem.style.display = "none"
              // checkElem.style.visibility = "hidden";                
            }
          };

    bindToggleVisibilityOnClick("egg", "brokenEgg");
```

```css
#egg       { display: block; }
#brokenEgg { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="egg"><p>hi</p></div>
<div id="brokenEgg"><p>hi2</p></div>
```

Comment: as i told another user on here im a pre schooler at best when it comes to js so thank you a MILLION times for your help! im going to try this out and get back with you so thanks again!

Comment: @altitudeup Please try the code now, not before the edit! There was a syntax error with my `.onclick` function bindings. Try run the code snippet to see how it should work. Bear in mind your elements ***must*** have a `display` property set for the function to change the `style.display` of the element (e.g., if you try to use this on an element without `display` set in your CSS (e.g., `p { margin: 20px; }`) `p` needs `display` property before the above function works).

Comment: Hey@Nick Bull its kind of working its going from hi to hi2 back to hi when its clicked.

Comment: Do you want it to only happen once, i.e., from one image to the next then not revert? I thought you might want it to return on further clicks. I'll update

Comment: @altitudeup Updated.

Comment: yes siir i tried the updated one but when it gets too hi2 you cant click on it like the first one you sent.

Comment: @altitudeup Not sure I understand - do either of those examples answer your question? If not, what needs to happen differently?

Comment: Hey @Nick Bull i think im confusing you im sorry about that. so say if you had team1 (hi &hi1) team2 (hi2 &hi3) team3 (hi4 & hi5) when you click hi it turns into hi1, hi1 disappears without a click and turns into one of the other teams randomly random team every time. click hi2 it turns into hi3  and hi4 when clicked turns into hi5 that should be everytime, the only thing that should change random is the teams.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly you ca use an object instead of an array for myShapes.

```
var myShapes = {
 "egg.png": "brokeEgg.png",
...
}
```

so when you click an image you can find the paired one.